# Выводит одинаковое время JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

В этом куске кода, получаю текущее клиентское время и его вывожу, только оно почему-то всегда одно и тоже:

```
var time;
var currentDate = new Date();

socket.on('private', function(data){
        time = currentDate.getHours() +":"+ currentDate.getMinutes() +":"+ currentDate.getSeconds();
console.log(time);
    });
```

Comment: Может секунды отличаются?

Comment: Net, v etom i prikol

Comment: Ответил ниже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var currentDate = new Date(); вы получили текущее время.
В чем ошибка:

Потом в функции используете его через другие промежутки времени. Но currentDate получено  при инициализации страницы и это было в другое время. 
Объявляйте currentDate в теле функции и будет вам счастье

```
socket.on('private', function(data){
var currentDate = new Date();
 time = currentDate.getHours() +":"+ currentDate.getMinutes() +":"+ currentDate.getSeconds();
console.log(time);
});
```